# Puppeteer not recognizing a node

Tags: ember.js, puppeteer, cucumberjs

I have some http I'm attempting to automate with CucumberJS and puppeteer:

```
<button data-test-foo="true" id="ember1213" class="ao-button ao-button--primary ao-button--large ao-button--block ember-view">
<!---->  <span class="ao-button__label">View Related Payment Requests</span>
</button>
```

When I attempt to page.clisk it:

```
async selectBeginImportButton() {
    await this.page.click('[data-test-foo="true"]');
}
```

I get an error:

```
✖ And I go to the Import files # features/step_definitions/login_steps.js:58
   Error: No node found for selector: [data-test-foo="true"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you are trying to click button before it's rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait for the element to be added to the DOM before clicking it.

```
const element = await page.waitForSelector( '[data-test-foo="true"]' );
await element.click();
```